What exactly is Abraham's bosom compared to Paradise in Lukes gospel? How did the rich man end up in hades and how was he able to see Abraham's bosom?
Luke 16:22-24

"One day the poor man died and was carried away by the angels to
Abraham’s side. The rich man also died and was buried. And being in
torment in Hades, he looked up and saw Abraham a long way off, with
Lazarus at his side. ‘Father Abraham!’ he called out, ‘Have mercy on
me and send Lazarus to dip the tip of his finger in water and cool my
tongue, because I am in agony in this flame!"

Jesus told the criminal on the cross (Luke 23:43) “I assure you: Today you will be with Me in paradise.”
Now, Jesus told the story of the rich man and the poor man and he believed in Abraham's bosom. But the criminal was not going to Abraham's bosom nor Hades but to Paradise. Can this be explained?

Search this site and Christianity.SE for existing answers to these questions, which have been asked and answered before. ¶Also, you say Jesus "believed in Abraham's bosom", without any support. The story was a parable, useful as a metaphor but not to be taken literally. If people today make an analogy referring to Darth Vader or Voldemort, that doesn't mean that they believe they were real people.

This question is similar to: How would the Jewish people understand Abraham's bosom and the bosom of The Father?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@RayButterworth, explain the metaphor for Abraham's bosom. I guess Hades and Paradise are metaphor's and aren't real either?

@RayButterworth, I view the provided question before I asked my question and it does not provided an explanation. The criminal was not going to Abraham's bosom nor Hades but to Paradise. Please explain!

@RayButterworth- My original question is, "What exactly is Abraham's bosom compared to Paradise in Lukes gospel? How did the rich man end up in hades and how was he able to see Abraham's bosom?"

You could see my answer to Is the thief on the cross the first person saved under the new covenant?. ¶But really each posting on this site is supposed to ask a single question about the possible intended meanings of single scripture. Asking multiple questions about multiple scriptures isn't allowed.

@RayButterworth, WRT I don't see either of these statements meaning Heaven. In Christian doctrine Heaven is opposite to Hades. Paradise is also equivalent to Heaven but in these verses Heaven is not used and that raises a flag for me. Also for the rich man to be able to see Hades from Abraham's bosom, this also raises  a flag for me.

Questions about doctrine should be asked on the Christianity.SE site, not here. E.g. you say "Paradise is also equivalent to Heaven", but that is the teaching of some but not all Christian denominations. (E.g. Paradise can refer to the Earth itself in the Kingdom of God during the Millennium following Christ's return, and the thief will be resurrected there in the second general resurrection, still mortal and still unsaved. That example involves at least four doctrinal positions, which just illustrates why this question just doesn't belong here.)

@RayButterworth, you should reframe from trying to answer the question with your doctrine if it is not appropriate here. When not having enough details in a passage of scripture we should be well equip to say there are not enough details to explain the passage.

This question is similar to: Is there a contradiction between Isaiah 38:17-19 & Luke 23:43?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

there is no exact answer based on the Bible. For Jewish traditions I recommend this article in the Jewish Enclyclopedia. https://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/362-abraham-s-bosom

The text in question is clear about certain differences between 'the bosom of Abraham' and Hades. It gives some information as to why the rich man ended up in the latter, but never implies that merely being a beggar would lead to being 'in Abraham's bosom', nor that merely being rich would lead to being in torments in Hades. It speaks of "a great chasm" between the former and the latter, and that there could be no crossing of that 'divide' by people who had died. Yet none of that deals with the question, as it is asking about Paradise.
However, if we keep the word 'Paradise' out of the answer (as the text in question does itself), then we can understand what 'the bosom of Abraham' and Hades mean in relation to each other, and then go back to Paradise to see why it needs to be kept out of the Luke account.
The Bosom of Abraham - This speaks of a relationship, not a position. The translation used in the question wrongly says that Lazarus was taken "to Abraham's side". No, he wasn't. He found himself in Abraham's bosom. It is stated twice in the text that he was in Abraham's bosom but not even once "at his side". That is the way modern translations often mistranslate the Greek.
They did it when John's gospel spoke of the Son of God being "in the bosom of the Father" (John 1:18), wrongly saying, "at the Father's side". Their error is, at least, consistent. However, the Greek word is 'kolpos' which means 'hollow thing'. It is the equivalent of the Hebrew 'chob', which means 'hidden place', e.g.

"I covered my transgressions as Adam, by hiding mine iniquity in my
bosom"  Job 31:33 K.J.V.

But anyone found at either Abraham's side, or the Father's side, occupies a position. They are in a definable place next to someone else. There is an element of separation between the two, as "at the side of" precludes any merging in union, one with the other. That is why correct translation of the Greek text when it has 'kolpos' must clearly and faithfully show that a privileged, intimate relationship is being spoken of. The text in question is about the after-physical-life state of Lazarus being intimately bound up with the patriarch Abraham, in glory. Lazarus is not standing (or sitting) next to Abraham. He is in a spiritually deep and intimate relationship with Abraham.
Same with the risen Christ in John 1:18. Sometimes the scriptures depict him as seated at the Father's side, other times as standing at the Father's side, yet again as being in the centre of the Father's throne in heaven. But in John 1:18 the word kolpos is used to denote the intimate relationship the Son of God has with God the Father in heaven.
Paradise - This means, then, that Paradise is not what Luke 16 is about, for when Jesus spoke of the repentant thief being with him in Paradise that day, he spoke of that man finding himself in a place - in a spiritual 'location' outside of physical life. If Jesus had wanted to tell him that he would relate intimately to Christ in Paradise, the word kolpos would have been used. No. It wasn't. That man was assured that he and Jesus would be in Paradise, but his relationship with Jesus is not mentioned.
So, the answer to the first question is: Abraham's bosom in Luke 16 denotes the intimate relationship of Lazarus with Abraham, after Lazarus had died physically. Paradise is not mentioned, so needs to be kept out of our thinking about Luke 16:22-24.
And the answer to the second question is: the 'how' of the rich man ending up in Hades is not stated in the text (though the 'why' is explained in verses 25-31; ignoring what Moses and the prophets had instructed him in his lifetime, so neither would listening to one risen from the dead change that.) As for 'seeing' Lazarus in Abraham's bosom, that denoted an intimate relationship of bliss that the rich man knew was not his, therefore his indescribable torments.

@Anne- The KJV says, "And it came to pass, that the beggar died, and was (carried) by the angels into Abraham's bosom: the rich man also died, and was buried." The CSB states, “One day the poor man died and was (carried) away by the angels to Abraham’s side.[fn] The rich man also died and was buried." [Or to Abraham’s bosom ; lit to the fold of Abraham’s robe ; Jn 13:23] Your answer gives false information. You should research more before answering a two fold question.
